# Does a single crystal of pure iron produce an electromagnetic field, and what is the orientation of the field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Does a single crystal of pure iron have an electromagnetic field, and if so, what is the orientation of the field?

Comment: In bcc iron, the easy axes of magnetisation are along the cubic <110> directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure iron single crystal is ferromagnetic. In the crystal, there are usually many different domains with different spontaneous magnetization orientations which on the average give a zero macroscopic magnetization unless the iron has been magnetized before and displays remanence. When you apply an increasing external magnetic field, the domains with magnetization inclined towards the field direction will first increase and then turn their magnetization direction towards the field direction until finally the magnetization of the whole crystal will point in field direction and the magnetization saturates.

Answer (score 0):

Iron, like everything else, emits thermal radiation, whose spectrum depends on the temperature.

Comment: It seems like the OP is asking more about magnetization than radiation. That said, this does answer the question as written.

Comment: @probably_someone : Then maybe the OP should have written "magnetic field", rather than "electromagnetic field".

Comment: Fair enough. As I said, this does answer the question as written.

Comment: @probably_someone - It seems that akhmeteli was misled by the word "electromagnetic' in the title.

Comment: @freecharly He was not misled. He answered the question as written.

Comment: @probably_someone - You are right. This definitely doesn't  answer  the question.

Comment: @freecharly It answers the question as written. When you say "it doesn't answer the question," you are adding in your own guesses about what the OP was implying, but not writing, in asking the question. In this case your guesses were right, but that doesn't mean they always will be, so you can't fault someone for making different guesses about implications than you did.

Comment: @probably_someone - Sorry, you are definitely right, that "electromagnetic" is not a good  word in the question. On the other hand, one could argue that a magnetic field is in the club of electromagnetic fields.  But this would be hair splitting. Thus this answer is not wrong, but even taken correct as written,as it is,  it skips the orientation part of the question.

Comment: @probably_someone -Sorry for the confusion, I should have written. "This answers (partially) the question as worded but not as probably intended."